# Hosting Google App Engine application in own domain

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps, google-sites, domain-mapping

I have bought a new domain from **GoDaddy** using **Google Apps Free Edition** before a few years ago (before google stop offering the free edition of Google Apps). Then i mapped this new domain with my **Google Sites** web site.

Now i need to remove this domain from my **Google Sites** web site and point it to my new web site hosted on **Google App Engine**.

I tried to delete domain mapped to my **Google Sites** web site from google apps control panel to point my new web site hosted on **Google App Engine**. but i got below error.

> Server error
>
> We are unable to process your request at this time, please try again
>   later.

I have tried several times. but no result.

How can i solve this ? How can i remove my domain from my **Google Sites** web site and point it to my new web site hosted on **Google App Engine** ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to update the dns records on GoDaddy to point at your app engine URL.